# Autofilling with "0" into SQL DB if textbox is empty

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm wondering how to make my textbox autofill "0" if the user leaves the textbox empty.
This textbox is inserting its value into an SQL table.

This is the Parameter code:

```
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("cena1", zcena1.Text);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will check if your textbox has null or empty text:

```
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("cena1", string.IsNullOrEmpty(zcena1.Text) ? "0" : zcena1.Text);
```

If you also want to autofill with "0" when textbox are only white spaces, then use this code:

```
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("cena1", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(zcena1.Text) ? "0" : zcena1.Text);
```

Comment: I would suggest `string.IsNullOrEmpty`/`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of places to make this call, you could create an inline `Func<string, string>` to do this for you. (Centralizes the logic.)

```
Func<string, string> toIntOr0 = x => string.IsNullOrWhitespace(x) ? "0" : x;

prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("cena1", toIntOr0(zcena1.Text));
```

If you are using this to verify if the textbox is a number, I would watch out as this is not a good way to do it. If you're just looking for a default value, then this works just fine.